# How to create a chat message bubble for Flutter UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to create a message bubble where the time takes up the bottom right corner of the message bubble as shown in the photo.
[image]
This is similar to the layout of whatsapp. I tried using row and column but that would mean that the time will be at another column or row. I tried using stack, but the words went behind the timing when the string is too long. Anyone can suggest how can I go about this? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Also, in whatsapp, there is a small pointy spot on the bottom right of the message bubble for the last message that was sent by me. How would you go about checking if it is your latest message in your message collection?

Answer (score 1):

Try this packages

[pub.dev/packages/chat_bubbles](https://pub.dev/packages/chat_bubbles)

[pub.dev/packages/bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble)

Comment: Yup, thanks for sharing. But I was wondering, how do you put the time at the bottom right corner as seen in the photo above